# Pass controller complex data to directive after render

Tags: angularjs

just started learning angular, and having some trouble passing complex data from controller to directive that is executed afterRender. I have seen countless other posts but none seem to be my exact situations.

**On HTML side:**

```
<ul after-render="AssignSubCatExpnasion" class="inner">
<li class="titleLevelSecond" ng-repeat="SubCat1 in Categories[0].Children">
    <div class="titleLevelSecondDiv toggle">
        <span class="title"> {{ SubCat1.Name }} </span><span class="numbers">{{ SubCat1.Count }}</span>
    </div>
    <ul  class="inner">
        <li class="titleLevelThird" ng-repeat="SubCat2 in SubCat1.Children">
            <div class="titleLevelThirdDiv">
                <span class="title">{{ SubCat2.Name }}</span> <span class="numbers">{{ SubCat2.Count }}</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**On Angular Side:**

```
<script>
var appGetBetCategories = angular.module('BetCategories', []);
appGetBetCategories.controller('GetBetCategories', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:49780/api/betcategory").then(function (response) {
        $scope.Categories = response.data;
    });
});
appGetBetCategories.directive('afterRender', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var def = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        terminal: true,
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            Categories: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(scope.$eval(attrs.afterRender), 0);
        }
    };
    return def;
}]);
```

Without a directive, all expressions execute properly, but I need to run js function called 'AssignSubCatExpnasion' after I am done with API call and have rendered my controls. I know I need to pass my controller scope to directive somehow, just can't wrap my head on how, since I already calling a function inside after-render="".

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is your method AssignSubCatExpnasion ?

Comment: in a separate .js file, it is being called no problem

Comment: if you want to call after api, then you simply call inside your promise... like $http.get("http://localhost:49780/api/betcategory").then(function (response) {
        $scope.Categories = response.data;
       AssignSubCatExpnasion();
    });

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, it didn't call it, even just an alert inside that function wasn't called. That is why I pursued this route of calling afteRender.

Comment: Is your response is coming from API.?? Did you check $scope.Category in your console.??

Comment: Yes, without a directive, all data is fine, when I add afterRender my expressions do not resolve

Comment: What does your console show when you inspect your page? Check the error messages and if you can, post it here

Comment: No errors. All clear.